# add new properties to array of objects (assign specific values based existing property value)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

In an array of objects, how would I add **new properties with specific values** to specific objects - based on one of the **specific object's properties' values**. Yikes. That's a mouthful.

For example, here is an array of objects:

```
var data = [
    {"label":"event1","name":"Red Total","count":220,},
    {"label":"event2","name":"Green Total","count":330,},
    {"label":"event3","name":"Blue Total","count":440,},
    {"label":"overlap1","name":"Red","count":200,},
    {"label":"overlap2","name":"Green","count":300}
]
```

All of these objects should get two new properties: `x` and `y` . I know that a `label` with a value of `event1` should **always** be assigned an `x` of `0.5` and a `y` of `0.75`. I know that a `label` with a value of `event2` should **always** be assigned an `x` of `1 / 3` and a `y` of `0.235` etc... Below is what I'd like the result to be.

```
var data = [
    {"label":"event1","name":"Red Total","count":220,"x":0.5,"y":0.75},
    {"label":"event2","name":"Green Total","count":330,"x":0.333,"y":0.235},
    {"label":"event3","name":"Blue Total","count":440,"x":0.666,"y":0.235},
    {"label":"overlap1","name":"Red","count":200,"x":0.9,"y":0.9},
    {"label":"overlap2","name":"Green","count":300,"x":0.9,"y":0.9}
]
```

The x and y values are not yet stored in any particular place or format, they are merely known, so that is completely flexible.

**Idea 1:** Perhaps they should be stored as another array of objects with `label` as a common key and then merge the two objects somehow based upon that key's value? I dunno.

```
var xAndY = [
    {"label":"event1","x":0.5,"y":0.75},
    {"label":"event2","x":0.333,"y":0.235}
}
```

**Idea 2:** Or maybe store them as an array of pairs?

```
var xAndY = [
    [0.333,0.75],
    [0.666,0.235]
}
```

**More context:** I will also not always know which of the objects will be in the array. Sometimes `event1`, `event2`, `event3` will be there. Sometimes, only `event1` and `event2`. So, I'm thinking some kind of `if` statement. Like for Idea 1 (in plain language):

```
if label = event1, add these new properties x:0.5 and y:0.75
if label = event2, add these new properties x:0.666 and y:0.235
```

or Idea 2

```
if label = event1, add these new properties x:xAndY[0][0] and y:xAndY[0][1]
if label = event2, add these new properties x:xAndY[1][0] and y:xAndY[1][1]
```

Obviously I have no idea how to approach this. Thanks for any direction you can give me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a good place to use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Fmap) (potentially via lodash or underscore):

```
var data = [
    {"label":"event1","name":"Red Total","count":220,},
    {"label":"event2","name":"Green Total","count":330,},
    {"label":"event3","name":"Blue Total","count":440,},
    {"label":"overlap1","name":"Red","count":200,},
    {"label":"overlap2","name":"Green","count":300}
]

var valueMap = {
  event1: {
    x: 0.5,
    y: 0.75
  },
  event2: {
    x: 1,
    y: 2
  },
  event3: {
    x: 2,
    y: 4
  },
  overlap1: {
    x: 6,
    y: 3
  },
  overlap2: {
    x: 0.3,
    y: 0.1
  }
}

var fullData = data.map(function(el) {
  var values = valueMap[el.label];
  el.x = values.x;
  el.y = values.y;
  return el;
})
```

Comment: Ah, nice use, and a great example of map here. This leads to a much cleaner code solution to the one I posted.

Comment: The only caveat is that if there are any labels that aren't in `valueMap` and you try to access their x and y  values, an error will be thrown. So you may want an extra check for whether they exist.

Comment: @dnak Thanks for the heads up on the caveat. In my particular case, it'll be ok, but good to know for others who may read this.

Answer (score 0):

Going off of your **Idea 1** you could store the x and y values as JavaScript objects with the object keys being the different labels in your data array. You could then iterate through the data array (of objects) and assign the x and y values from the x_and_ys object if the label exists (see this example below).

```
var x_and_ys = {"event1": {"x": 0.5, "y": 0.75},
                "event2": {"x": 0.333, "y": 0.235}};

data.forEach(function (arrEntry, index) {
    if (x_and_ys[arrEntry["label"]] !== undefined) {
        for (var x_or_y in x_and_ys[arrEntry["label"]]) {
            arrEntry[x_or_y] = x_and_ys[arrEntry["label"]][x_or_y]; 
        }    
    }
});
```

See also this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/v4z020fs/

Comment: Thanks, this solution works great, and thanks for the JSFiddle. I agree with your comment though, that using map is cleaner.